# ERROR IN ANALYZING PROJECT IN JUNO ECLIPSE WITH SONARQUBE 4.5

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube4.5 with juno eclipse. I have linked my project in project explorer with project running in localhost:9000. But analysis failed with following exception,

```
Retrieve remote issues of project nexgenpos...
Start SonarQube analysis on nexgenpos...
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5
12:06:53.813 INFO  - Load global referentials...
12:06:54.425 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 631 ms
12:06:54.426 INFO  - Incremental mode
12:06:54.454 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\EIT-MUSTAK\.sonar\cache
12:06:54.478 INFO  - Install plugins
12:06:54.520 INFO  - Include plugins: 
12:06:54.521 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, jira, pdfreport, views, report, buildstability, scmactivity, buildbreaker
12:07:01.418 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:D:\sonar_nexgenpos_plugin\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\nexgenpos\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\.sonartmp\preview1413873416091-0
12:07:05.284 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'retail:nexerppos': sonar.sources
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.checkMandatoryProperties(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:289)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:125)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:114)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.projectBootstrap(ProjectScanContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:98)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 6 more
```

In sonar-project.properties, in "sonar.sources=D:/sonar_nexgenpos_plugin/nexgenpos/src" which is the path of my source code in the workspace is given. Analysis is showing in localhost:9000 successfully but failed in eclipse.

Sonar experts please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide logs in debug mode (there is a button in SonarQube Console view to enable debug output)? What is the name of your source folder in Eclipse (by chance maybe it contains "test" string)?

Comment: Do you have source folder in your project? You have to understand that Eclipse integration ignore the sonar-project.properties file. The SQ analysis is configured by looking at Eclipse metadata. Each source folder of your project (as seen by Eclipse) will be passed to sonar.sources.